# Executing sql file from another sql file

Tags: sql, file, oracle11g, sqlplus, spool

I have a `.sql` file with name `Alter_table.sql` which have the following code.

```
alter table mytable add newcolumn VARCHAR2(1);
```

I don't want to edit this file and add a spool command. However I need to execute `Alter_table.sql` by writing spool in another file (execute_sql.sql) which should look like the below. I am not sure of the correct syntax. Can anyone please help here?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET DEFINE OFF
SPOOL Alter_Table_STD_SOURCE.log

EXEC username/password@database `Alter_table.sql`

SPOOL OFF;
SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Comment: How are you running this - are you already connected to the database by this point?

Comment: I use command prompt, by which I first direct to that path (for eg c:\Scripts). Then I will give the commend sqlplus username/password@database. Then @execute_sql.sql

Comment: OK, then you are already connected, and you just need the `@Alter_table.sql` part of Gary's answer (instead of `exec`), without the explicit `connect`.

Answer (score 3):

(Thanks to Alex Poole) :-)

You need to connect first, then run your .sql file in the wrapper script using the '@' sign or 'START' commands:

```
...
-- Connect if not already connected.
CONNECT username/password@database

@Alter_table.sql

...
```

I'm not sure its a good idea to keep login/password in a file but you need to take security into account.

Comment: `@Alter_table.sql`, or [`start`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210918); not `exec`, which is shorthand for an anonymous PL/SQL block.